# Countif or CASE with multiple conditions

Tags: google-bigquery, case, countif

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to count products being placed in a online cart .   I have ranked the first 3 items placed in a cart by purchase time(time they were put in the cart not actual check out time), but now am struggling to figure out a way to count the different combinations of items going into the cart.

Counting the individual ranks is easy enough, but I need to figure out a count for purchasing product 1 first and product 1 second as well as all the combinations possible (5 products total).  I only need to count first items in the cart, all combinations of first item in cart to second item in cart, and all combinations of second item in cart to third third item in cart.

```
SELECT
COUNTIF(product = 'Product1' and rank = 1) as firstpurchase_product1,
COUNTIF((product = 'Product1' and rank = 1) and (product = 'Product1' and rank = 2)) as firstpurchase_product1_secondpurchase_product1,
COUNTIF((product = 'Product1' and rank = 1) and (product = 'Product2' and rank = 2)) as firstpurchase_product1_secondpurchase_product2,
#code would continue for all combinations.

FROM(

customer_info.customer_id as customer_id,
customer_info.session_id as session_id,
customer_info.product_purchased as product,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_info.session_id ORDER BY customer_info.purchase_time ASC) AS rank
FROM customer_purchases cp,
WHERE p_date >= "2022-04-12" 
)rnk

where rnk.finish_rank in (1,2,3)
```

This seems like a lot of code, is there a better way to do it?  The query is returning 0 for all line except when counting just first purchases, should I be using CASE instead?

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

***Example of input:***

Product 1, Product 2, Product 3

Product 1, Product 1, Product 1

Product 4, Product 2, Product 1

Product 3, Product 3, Product 5

Product 4, Product 2, Product 4

--this goes on for hundreds of lines

***Output***:
Count Product 1 in first column

Count Product 2 in first column

#continue for all 5

Count of customers who put product 1 in cart first AND product 1 in cart
second

Count of customers who put product 1 in cart first AND product 2 in cart second

###continue with all combinations with product 1

Count of customers who put product 2 in cart first and product 1 in cart second

Count of customers who put product 2 in the cart first and product 2 in the cart second

###continue with all combinations of product 2,3,4, and 5

Comment: A friend mentioned maybe converting to a string and counting the results, that might work? I am not sure how to do that though.

Comment: not clear what exactly the input data and expected output - please provide example of both so we can help you. check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have updated the code so hopefully that helps.  I am really just trying to figure out what to put in the select statement.  I clarified the intent which is more to do with capturing the order things go into a customers cart for online orders.  The session_id is their individual online session, as I want to capture repeat customers to see how they interact different when the are making purchases.

Comment: As mentioned by @MikhailBerlyant, can you please add sample input data with the expected output for that input data?

Comment: added some more clarity around the request, if that isn't helpful please let me know

Comment: Hello @Nova700. Can you explicitly show how the output table will look like? For the first 5 input rows, how would the output table look like with the counts as per your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to `GROUP BY` a set of columns (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`) and produce a count of the number of times each combination occurs.

Possibly (it's a little unclear from your wording - a well-formatted table showing example raw data and desired results for that example would be helpful), you want to know an overall count for values of `item1` regardless of the other items. This can be achieved via `GROUP BY ROLLUP(item1, item2, item3)`.

So, our aim is to get an *unaggregated* table with those columns, so that we can aggregate it as described!

You have a long-format table (customer ID, session ID, product, rank) and we want a wide-format table with a column for each value of rank. This is a `PIVOT` operation:

```sql
WITH rnk AS (
  SELECT
     customer_id,
     session_id,
     product_purchased AS product,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY purchase_time ASC) AS rank
   FROM customer_info
  WHERE p_date >= "2022-04-12"
QUALIFY rank IN (1,2,3)
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM rnk PIVOT(
      ANY_VALUE(product) AS item FOR rank in (1,2,3)
    )
)

SELECT
    item_1,
    item_2,
    item_3,
    COUNT(*) AS N
  FROM
    pivoted
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(item_1, item_2, item_3)
```

Does that get you what you want?

---

A couple of features to note:

1. I use common table expressions (WITH) to make this more readable
2. `QUALIFY` is a filter clause to apply to the output of a window clause
3. Pivoting requires an aggregation function because in general there could be many records with the same value of session, product, and rank. Here we know there will be one record only, so it's safe to use `ANY_VALUE` (which 'aggregates' by non-deterministically choosing one of the values).
4. Just to prevent confusion: `ROLLUP` will give you something like 'Product A', NULL, NULL for some of its records - this doesn't mean items 2 and 3 don't exist, it's just how it signals those records that group only by item 1 and aggregate over all values of the other items.

Comment: This is great!  Very close to what I was trying to accomplish, but my results were coming up very strange with null in item_1 which shouldn't be possible.  Any idea what might be causing this?  my most common item purchase was null, null, null not sure how that is even a thing?  Any advice?  Also sorry for the long delay in response, work has been exceptionally busy and hadn't had time to try this out!

Comment: Please refer to point #4 at the bottom of my answer. This is due to ROLLUP aggregating over everything. If this isn't what you want, simply remove ROLLUP to get rid of the summary rows.

Comment: So for example NULL/NULL/NULL tells you how many journeys there were in total, Product 1/NULL/NULL tells you how many journeys started with Product 1, etc.

Comment: okay that makes it much clearer thank you Paddy!  I am seeing  instances like this: Product 2, Product 2, null, n 500  and then Product 2, Product 2, null, n 490.   What is the distinction between the two?

Comment: That's unexpected. Is it possible you have two products with very similar names? You could try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pivoted WHERE item_1 = 'Product 2' AND item_2 = 'Product 2'` to check how many of those journeys (`N`) you're expecting.

Comment: The product names are all very different, and the counts for individual lines are producing the higher count of the 2 N's in the rollout.   Just looked again and I have 3 null, null, null.  My guess would be something with the pivot, but I am not very familiar with them.  The roll out count also appears to be off.  The line of product 1, product 1, product 1 has a N of 3 in the rollout but just looking at the result of of the RNK section of the query there is at least 6 sessions in the first couple hundred results.  I will keep messing around with it, but any ideas would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite hard to diagnose this sort of problem without knowing what the exact data are. You could check whether you get sensible results without ROLLUP, and try something like `COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS N` - your original question doesn't say much about the IDs so it's not impossible that this will be more accurate.